# How to instrument/profile memory(heap, pointers) reads and writes in C?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management

I know this might be a bit vague and far-fetched (sorry, stackoverflow police!).

Is there a way, without external forces, to instrument (track basically) each pointer access and track reads and writes - either general reads/writes or quantity of reads/writes per access. Bonus if it can be done for all variables and differentiate between stack and heap ones.

Is there a way to wrap pointers in general or should this be done via custom heap? Even with custom heap I can't think of a way.

Ultimately I'd like to see a visual representation of said logs that would show me variables represented as blocks (of bytes or multiples of) and heatmap over them for reads and writes.

Ultra simple example:

```
int i = 5;
int *j = &i;

printf("%d", *j); /* Log would write *j was accessed for read and read sizeof(int) bytes
```

Attempt of rephrasing in more concise manner:

(How) can I intercept (and log) access to a pointer in C without external instrumentation of binary? - bonus if I can distinguish between read and write and get name of the pointer and size of read/write in bytes.

Comment: It is *implementation specific*: depends upon the compiler, the libc, the operating system, etc... Standard C99 or C11 does not know about instrumenting or profiling. So **edit your question** to improve it by telling more about your C implementation and your code

Comment: Also, explain why do you ask that..... Without additional edits I will soon downvote this question since unclear, and might vote for closing since too broad...

Comment: Why do I ask? Why wouldn't I? Also, it is explained at the end of the question. I would like to log each access to all or select pointers and differentiate reads and writes, if possible, and log how much was read/written. Implementation doesn't matter since I would like to see ANY way this is possible. If it does matter, indeed, then GCC 5.2 (OSX, Windows/MinGW and Linux) and everything that comes with it vanilla.

Comment: I downvoted (but I am typing an answer) since you did not edit your question...

Comment: I did, but I can't write comment and edit at the same time.

Comment: You should explain why do you ask. Looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  to me...

Comment: I did explain. Read again. Again - I want to log each memory access without (external) binary instrumentation. And I'm asking if this is possible at all and if so how. As to why - it doesn't matter for the question. But since you're keen on that as well - I want to generate heatmap of memory access to visualize memory access patterns in my program (depends on data - hence I want to instrument) and use that for further .. things. I can do this via intel pin, but I wonder if I can do that without external binary instrumentation because then I could have that as a 'feature' within my program.

Comment: No. What kind of bug are you chasing? On What kind of software? You never told anything about your bugs or your software.

Comment: Not to sound abrasive..but Did I mention any bugs anywhere? Why do I have to discuss my program, usage, nature of the program? Shall I send in a copy of my passport as well? I asked a simple question to which I have no answer for. Is it possible, in C, to log memory access (reads and writes and size) without external binary instrumentation like with intel pin. All that without wrapping variables into getters/setters, of course. If yes - how, if no - thank you for your time. /EOD since it's OT. Question is here, there's an answer or there isn't.

Comment: Your question is not simple, and is certainly too broad.

Comment: "(How) can I intercept (and log) access to a pointer in C without external instrumentation of binary?" - bonus if I can distinguish between read and write and get name of the pointer and size of read/write in bytes. I can't get clearer than this. Let this stand for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

I guess (or hope for you) that you are developing on Linux/x86-64 with a *recent* [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (5.2 in october 2015) or perhaps [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) compiler (3.7).

I also guess that you are tracking a naughty bug, and not asking this (too broad) question from a purely theoretical point of view.

<sup>(Notice that practically there is no *simple* answer to your question, because in practice C compilers produce machine code close to the hardware, and most hardware do not have sophisticated instrumentations like the one you dream of)</sup>

Of course, compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Use the debugger (`gdb`), notably its watchpoint facilities which are related to your issue. Use also [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). 
Notice also that GDB (recent versions like 7.10) is scriptable in Python (or Guile), and you could code some scripts for GDB to assist you.

Notice also that recent GCC & Clang/LLVM have several sanitizers. Use some of the [`-fsanitize=` debugging options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html), notably the [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) with `-fsanitize=address`; they are instrumenting the code to help in detecting pointer accesses, so they are sort-of doing what you want. Of course, the performance of the instrumented generated code is decreasing (depending on the sanitizer, can be 10 or 20% or a factor of 50x).

At last, you might even consider adding your own instrumentation by **customizing your compiler**, e.g. with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) -a high level domain specific language designed for such customization tasks for GCC. This would take months of work, unless you are already familiar with GCC internals (then, only several weeks). You could add an "optimization" pass inside GCC which would instrument (by changing the [Gimple](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html) code) whatever accesses or stores you want.

Read more about [aspect-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

Notice also that if your C code is generated, that is if you are [meta-programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming), then changing the C code generator might be very relevant. Read more about [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29) and [homoiconicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity). [Dynamic software updating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_software_updating) is also related to your issues.

Look also into profiling tools like [oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net) and into [sound static source analyzers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) like [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/).

You could also run your program inside some (instrumenting) [emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulator) (like [Qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/), [Unisim](http://unisim-vp.org/site/index.html), etc...).

You might also compile for a fictitious architecture like [MMIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMIX) and instrument its emulator.